# wxpython : how to open a Dialog directly from the MenuBar

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to find a method to open a wx.Dialog from a MenuBar without klicking a MenuEntry first.

Example:

```
class Custom_MenuBar(wx.MenuBar):
    def __init__(self, parent, style=0):
        wx.MenuBar.__init__(self, style)

        # About-Menu
        aboutmenu = wx.Menu()
        about_id = wx.Window.NewControlId()
        aboutmenu.Append(about_id, "&About", "show About-Menu")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self._about, id=about_id)
        self.Append(aboutmenu, "About Menu")

        # Menubar aktivieren
        parent.SetMenuBar(self)

    def _about(self, _event):
        wx.adv.AboutBox(wx.adv.AboutDialogInfo())
```

This example (with a frame as parent) shows a MenuBar with an entry "About Menu".
Clicking on this entry shows a MenuItem called "About", and finally clicking on "About" opens the AboutBox.

I want to spare clicking onto the MenuItem, instead open the AboutBox directly when activating the "About Menu".

An idea was to derive from wx.Menu, but as wx.Menu does not inherit from wx.Window, I do not find an Id to Bind to.
My question is: what happens from the event point of view when an entry ("About Menu") is clicked in the MenuBar; then opening a Menu? Is there a possibility to interfere there? Any other idea?

PS: using python 3.8.0 and wxPython 4.0.7.post2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have options, depending on exactly what you want to achieve.
Using the menu event options you can use the menu's Id or the text if there is no Id ( menu open ).
The following shows the most obvious options.

```
import wx
import wx.stc
import wx.adv
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MenuFrame(None, title="Menu Dialogue")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()

        return True

class MenuFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MenuFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Attributes
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.txtctrl = wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl(self.panel,
                                   style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        # Layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.txtctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.CreateStatusBar() # For output display

        # Setup the Menu
        menu = wx.MenuBar()

        # File Menu
        filem = wx.Menu()
        filem.Append(wx.ID_NEW, "New")
        filem.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "Open")
        filem.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "Save")
        filem.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, "Save_As")
        menu.Append(filem, "&File")

        # About Menu
        aboutm = wx.Menu()
        self.about_id = wx.NewIdRef()
        aboutm.Append(self.about_id, "&About Info", "Show About-Menu")
        menu.Append(aboutm,"&About")

        self.SetMenuBar(menu)

        # Event Handlers
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnMenu)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU_OPEN, self.OnMenuOpen)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU_HIGHLIGHT, self.OnMenuHighlight)

    def OnMenu(self, event):
        evt_id = event.GetId()
        if evt_id == self.about_id:
            info = wx.adv.AboutDialogInfo()
            info.SetDescription("Menu Clicked "+str(evt_id)+" selected\n")
            wx.adv.AboutBox(info)

    def OnMenuOpen(self, event):
        evt_id = event.GetId()
        Dlg = False
        if evt_id == 0:
            obj = event.GetMenu()
            if obj.GetTitle() == "&About":
                Dlg = True
        if Dlg:
            info = wx.adv.AboutDialogInfo()
            info.SetDescription("Menu Opened "+str(evt_id)+" selected\n")
            wx.adv.AboutBox(info)

    def OnMenuHighlight(self, event):
        evt_id = event.GetId()
        if evt_id == self.about_id:
            info = wx.adv.AboutDialogInfo()
            info.SetDescription("Menu Highlight "+str(evt_id)+" selected\n")
            wx.adv.AboutBox(info)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: One small point I don't understand:
when using your example, if you open a menu with a klick, here "File" menu, without selecting an item, and then move the mouse to the menu managed by EVT_MENU_OPEN, here "About", MenuFrame.OnMenuOpen() is called without a further mouse click.
Why that?

Comment: Because the `MenuBar` has focus, when the cursor moves to `About` that menu opens (drops down), firing the `EVT_MENU_OPEN`, where the `if obj.GetTitle() == "&About"` test is applied. I hope that's clear.

Comment: Also, because the menu opens but no specific menu item is yet selected, there is no event `Id` to check against, thus we check the `Title`.

Comment: What had puzzled me was, that one time a click was needed to bring up the dialog, whereas another time the dialog appeared without click.
With tests according to your explanation I understood that the click was necessary to set the focus; once the MenuBar has the focus, EVT_MENU_OPEN is fired whenever the pointer reaches the "sensivity zone" of any Menu entry.
Unfortunately I found rarely any documentation concerning EVT_MENU_OPEN.